# How to change IPython console width

Tags: ipython, spyder

There is a vertical line in the Editor. When I run code, the results go to the next line once this vertical line is reached.

Right now I get this:

```
3433 3344 3434 3434 3434 3434/
343 4645 345345 56546 35345/
3656 546546 3534 3553 5645
```

I want the console output to be this

```
3433 3344 3434 3434 3434 3434 343 4645 345345 56546 35345 3656 546546 3534  3553 5645
```

I want my code output to take up the entire width of my screen.

I'm using IPython within Spyder(Ptyhon 3.6) from Anaconda

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing a numpy array, you can set your "linewidth" in this way:

```
import numpy as np
l_w = 1000 #The number of elements to display before truncation in console
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=l_w)
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, right now (May/2018) it is not possible to configure the width output text can take in our consoles.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: It's still not possible. Output text wraps in the console, sorry.